# Aggregation unwind multiple arrays $lookup as multiple fields for projection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is my current query:

```
Follow.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "user": Types.ObjectId(user_id) 
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$following"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "following",
      "foreignField": "createdById",
      "as": "followingUsers"
    }
  }, {
    $project: {
        "user": 1,
        "followingUsers": 1
    }
  }
])
```

This query is run on a document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a271a93a19d690b25a3e181"),
    "user" : ObjectId("5a271a4f50261a3c1695a391"),
    "following" : [
        ObjectId("5a257c87086eb00712fd02ec"),
        ObjectId("5a257a79086eb00712fd02eb")
    ],
    "followers" : [
        ObjectId("5a257a79086eb00712fd02eb")
    ]
}
```

And gives a result like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a271a93a19d690b25a3e181"),
    "user" : ObjectId("5a271a4f50261a3c1695a391"),
    "followingUsers" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a257a79086eb00712fd02eb"),
            "email" : "email@gmail.com",
            "username" : "username",
            "email_verified" : true,
            "created" : ISODate("2010-12-04T16:40:25.670Z"),
            "__v" : 0,
            "last_login" : ISODate("2010-12-06T21:14:25.538Z"),
            "is_active" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

The above unwinds only one of the arrays and follows up the lookup.

I want to, in one scoop (assuming that is possible)

- unwind both the `$following` and `$followers` array fields
- `$lookup` both of the array fields independently
- then have both come out `as`, say, `followingUsers` and `followersUsers`

So end up with something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a271a93a19d690b25a3e181"),
    "user" : ObjectId("5a271a4f50261a3c1695a391"),
    "followingUsers" : [
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5a257a79086eb00712fd02eb"),
          ....
        }
    ],
    "followersUsers": [
        { 
          "_id" : ObjectId("5a257a79086eb00712fd02eb"),
          ....
        }
    ]
}
```

Am I even sane to imagine something like this in MongoDB?

Comment: No $unwind needed in 3.4. You can try below query in 3.4. `Follow.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "user": Types.ObjectId(user_id) 
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "following",
      "foreignField": "createdById",
      "as": "followingUsers"
    }
  }, {
    $lookup: {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "followers",
      "foreignField": "createdById",
      "as": "followersUsers"
    }
  }
])`

Comment: will give it a try, thanks.

Comment: @Veeram can you kindly add it as the answer so I can mark it? Yes, it worked. Thanks. Didn't know there can be multiple lookup commands. And the tip about the no need for `$unwind`, nice.